# Android Studio: Using an external executable

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, ioexception

I would like to use an external executable within my android app.
It is distributed for different platforms and under windows it's a console program that can be used in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110415/how-to-bind-a-windows-console-application-with-java-application)
For Android the executable is called senpai-arm. I moved it to an Android folder and tried to start it in a similar way to the link above but it won't start.

```
 String storage = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
 // Create the proccess in JAVA
 Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(storage+ "/senpai-arm");
```

error message below:

`java.io.IOException: Error running exec()`.

Command: [/data/user/0/com.example.jp.fanfar/files/senpai-arm] Working Directory: null Environment: nul
 cause: Permission denied

Sorry that I didn't observe the cause Permission denied in my original question.
I rephrase my question a bit.

- Is it possible to start a program like this?
- What permissions do I need? I have read/write external storage permission.

(I have the source code in C++ and read about NDK but I was hoping to take a shortcut by using the distributed executable instead.)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475497/runtime-exec-not-working

Comment: Thank you sasikumar but I don't think it is the same issue. I have no white spaces in the command and no commas are inserted.